# How to convert columns into rows but with respect to specific column?

Tags: python, pandas, transpose, melt

How to convert columns into rows but with respect to specific column using python?

for example i have a data like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwxNp.png)

and i want result like this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyiux.png)

I used melt, transpose and some other functions but they didn't solve my problem

Comment: `melt` looks like the right choice, but you're going to have to put more effort into your question for us to help you. What code have you tried? Why didn't it solve your problem?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.